# how can i made docker work with my user (ubuntu)

Tags: docker, ubuntu

this is the current situation:

```
hamsterofdeath@HodVm:~$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/hamsterofdeath/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
hamsterofdeath@HodVm:~$ sudo docker ps
[sudo] password for hamsterofdeath: 
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
hamsterofdeath@HodVm:~$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/hamsterofdeath/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
hamsterofdeath@HodVm:~$ sudo groupadd docker
groupadd: group 'docker' already exists
hamsterofdeath@HodVm:~$ sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker
Adding user hamsterofdeath to group docker
hamsterofdeath@HodVm:~$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/hamsterofdeath/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
hamsterofdeath@HodVm:~$
```

cat /etc/group gives me "docker:x:996:hamsterofdeath"

logging out and in again changes nothing. i also tried:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
```

but it has no effect. what do i need to do?
i always get:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/hamsterofdeath/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

or

```
Error response from daemon: dial unix /home/hamsterofdeath/.docker/desktop/docker.raw.sock: connect: connection refused
```

with sudo, it works

there might be another(?) problem
i removed docker via

```
sudo apt remove docker
```

but the "docker" command still exists.

```
amsterofdeath@HodVm:~$ sudo apt remove docker
[sudo] password for hamsterofdeath: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'docker' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
hamsterofdeath@HodVm:~$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/hamsterofdeath/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
hamsterofdeath@HodVm:~$
```

Comment: That socket path looks unusual.  Do you have the `$DOCKER_HOST` environment variable set?  Among other things `sudo` will reset the environment so you might have access to the system `/var/run/docker.sock` file but not that `$HOME/.docker/...` path.

Comment: $DOCKER_HOST is not set. what should it be? why doesn't it "just work"? is "docker desktop" breaking things? i installed it to have a ui.

Comment: `$DOCKER_HOST` should usually be unset.  I'd expect it to normally look at `/var/run/docker.sock` on native Linux and it's possible that Docker Desktop is causing this, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Waht you could try:

1. Try restarting the bash process and probably the machine.
2. See if the docker group is associated with the .sock file
3. This should return nothing:

   `stat -c %U:%G /home/hamsterofdeath/.docker/desktop/docker.raw.sock |  grep -v root:docker`
   if it does do:

   `chown root:docker /home/hamsterofdeath/.docker/desktop/docker.raw.sock`
4. Is $USER filled with the correct data ?
5. Restart docker engine using sudo systemctl

Else go to [Post-Install](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) and try all the steps there especially since it seems to an VM restart it

Next Docker Desktop is rather sketchy. I personally recommend using the VS-Code Docker extension as it offers almost the same functionality as docker desktop and works fine with Ubuntu. See [Docker Extension VS-Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/overview)

Comment: 1. done many times. 2. how do i do this? 3. yes. 4. done many times. i also followed the post install steps a few times.

Comment: edited answer to contain details for 2 also see:
https://docs.datadoghq.com/security_platform/default_rules/cis-docker-1.2.0-3.15/ Also ls -l should help within  /home/hamsterofdeath/.docker/desktop/docker.raw.sock
see what it says 
ls -l should be:
-rwxr-xr-x 1  root docker    120    Mar 12 09:32 docker.raw.sock; See chwon command above

Comment: 3. the command returned "hamsterofdeath:hamsterofdeath". after running the second command nothing is returned

Comment: try docker again after relogging. And maybe just use the standart installaation path for docker in /var/run to try from scratch. What we did was set the owner of the .sock file to root and the group to docker. But since you were the owner already it should have worked anyway. I would recommend installing docker freshly using standard paths and the apt interface

Comment: 2. srwxrwxr-x 1 root           docker            0 Jun 15 22:05 docker.raw.sock

Comment: does docker ps work now ? Otherwize as David Maze suggested try using the standart paths for docker.

Comment: docker and docker desktop were fighting against each other. i deleted one of them